setPositiveButton text not appearing
After adding a splash screen to my app, the text of my setPositiveButton  - "Finish" - has stopped appearing. Where the "Finish" should appear, there's a blank space. But clicking that blank space correctly executes the finishQuiz() method that contains the setPositiveButton.
Here's the code for the splash screen:
package com.example.numbers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 7000);

    }

}

Can anyone see why the addition of a splash screen has prevented the setPositiveButton text ("Finish") appearing?
Here's my MainActivity file, which contains the setPositiveButton:
package com.example.numbers;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView questionTextView;
    TextView totalQuestionTextView;
    Button ansA,ansB,ansC,ansD;
    Button btn_submit;

    int score=0;
    int totalQuestion = QuestionAnswer.question.length;
    int currentQuestionIndex =0;
    String selectedAnswer="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        totalQuestionTextView = findViewById(R.id.total_question);
        questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question);
        ansA = findViewById(R.id.ans_a);
        ansB = findViewById(R.id.ans_b);
        ansC= findViewById(R.id.ans_c);
        ansD = findViewById(R.id.ans_d);
        btn_submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        ansA.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansB.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansC.setOnClickListener(this);
        ansD.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this);


        totalQuestionTextView.setText("You have "+totalQuestion +" questions to answer");

        loadNewQuestion();
    }

    private void loadNewQuestion(){
        if(currentQuestionIndex == totalQuestion){
            finishQuiz();
            return;
        }
        questionTextView.setText(QuestionAnswer.question[currentQuestionIndex]);
        ansA.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][0]);
        ansB.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][1]);
        ansC.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][2]);
        ansD.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][3]);

        selectedAnswer="";

    }

    private void finishQuiz(){
        String passStatus;
        if(score >= totalQuestion*0.6){
            passStatus = "You passed - well done!";
        }else{
            passStatus = "You failed this time - but keep trying!";
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(passStatus)
                .setMessage("You scored "+score+" out of "+totalQuestion)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Finish",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                moveTaskToBack(true);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                                System.exit(1);
                            }
                        })
                .show();
    }


     private void restartQuiz(){
        score = 0;
        currentQuestionIndex=0;
        loadNewQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        ansA.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansB.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansC.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        ansD.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        Button clickedButton = (Button) view;

        if(clickedButton.getId() == R.id.btn_submit) {
            if(!selectedAnswer.isEmpty()){
                if(selectedAnswer.equals(QuestionAnswer.correctAnswers[currentQuestionIndex])){
                    score++;
                }else{
                    clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
                currentQuestionIndex++;
                loadNewQuestion();
            }else{

            }
        }
        else{
            selectedAnswer=clickedButton.getText().toString();
            clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }

    private class OnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    }
}


In the attached image, the space where the "Finish" should appear is circled in red.

Can you share more details as image here to get the clarification of your question? The above content still create many confusion.

Mea culpa. The cause of my setPositiveButton text disappearing after I added a splash screen was in my themes.xml file. When I added the splash screen I set the primary colour to white in themes.xml. As the default buttons and the dialogue background were both therefore white, the text of the setPositiveButton could not be seen. Doh!
